# Use loop in brackets

Tags: python, loops, telegram, telebot

I'm working on telegram bot, and I need to create the message with 16 buttons, each row contains 4 elements. Elements I need to extract and insert/paste into buttons are in the list. I need to write the code like:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)
markup.add(
    for i in list: 
        print(i.text)
)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose: ', reply_markup=markup)
```

It's the theoretical example, how I need to do.

I tried to do it with loop outside from `markup.add` like:

```
for i in list:
    markup.add(i.text)
```

But in this case, each element takes place one row. Can you please help?

Comment: So it should be like `markup.add(1,2,3,4,...)`?

Comment: You need to introduce a second counter, when the second counter is for example = 4, then go to a new row and reset it

Comment: `ì` is a number. `i.text` doesn't make sense

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `markup.add(*(i.text for i in list))`.